# Finding the index of the subgroup of $A$ in $B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

> Consider the following two subgroups $A$, $B$ of the group $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of one variable rational
> polynomials under addition:
>
> $A = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\mid p$ has degree at most $2\}$, and
>
> $B = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \mid p$ has degree at most $2$, and $p(\mathbb{Z}) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}\}$.
> Then the index $[B : A]$ of $A$ in $B$ equals:

I was trying to figure out how does the subgroup $B$ look like ,

Let $a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$ be a polynomial. Then, we see that $a_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and it $a_2,a_1$ will satisfy the equation $n^2a_2 + na_1 = (n^2-n)a_2 + nk$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k = a_2 + a_1$.

Now, if $n(n-1).\frac{p_2}{q_2} + nk \in \mathbb{Z}$.So, $q_2 \mid n$ or $q_2 \mid n-1$ if such a condition arises then the only possibility for $q_2$ is $q_2 = 2$.(As we dont want $q_2$ to be $1$)

Also $n^2a_2 + na_1 = -(n^2-n)a_1 + n^2k  $

So we see that $q_1 = 2 $ or $q_1 = 1$.

So the best possible guess for me is that $[B:A] = 2$ as $a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 \in A$ and

$(a_2 +  k_1\frac{1}{2})x^2 + (a_1 + k_2\frac{1}{2})x + a_0) \in B $.

I don't think my reasoning is quite accurate. Can someone fix it?

How do I proceed next ?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this exercice, one should remember that the polynomial $P(X)= {X(X+1)\over 2}$ is in $B$. (its value at $n$ is the sum of the $n-1$ first integers, and $P(-n)= P(n-1)$

Now let $p(x)=a x^2+bx+c \in B$, then $p-2a P=(b-a)x+c$ is also in $B$ so that $c,b-a$ are in $\bf Z$. (take $x=0,1$.

Conversely, if $a-b,c$ are integers, $p$ is in $B$ iff $2aP$ is iff $2a\in Z$ (take $x=1$.

In conclusion $p\in B$ iff $2a, b-a, c$ are in $Z$. from this is is clear that $[B:A]= 2$.

Comment: is my way then wrong? Actually it didnt occur to me that you can proceed like that.How did you think of it?

Comment: The study of polynomial such that $P(Z)$ is a subset of $Z$ is quite classical. The method I propose enables you to solve the same problem for any degree : jus consider $P_n(X)= {X(X+1)...(X+n-1)\over n!}$, and note that $P_0,...P_n$ is a set of generators of the corresponding abelian group

Answer (score 0):

We can use the fact that the set of integer valued polynomials has a $\mathbb{Z}-$basis consisting of binomial coefficients. For any $p(x)\in B$, we have $p(x)=a+bx+c\frac{x(x-1)}{2}$ such that $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$. Now
\begin{align*}
p(x) +A &=a+bx+c\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A\\
&= c\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A.
\end{align*}

If $c$ is even, say $c=2k$ then $$c\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A= 2k \frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A=0+A.$$

If $c$ is odd, say $c=2k+1$ then $$c\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A= (2k+1) \frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A=\frac{x(x-1)}{2}+A.$$